How to expose a "param" like React does in onChange, onClick, etc.?
I want to do what React does with onClick, onChange, etc.
React does:
onClick={(event)=>console.log(event)}

I want to do:
someProp={(wanna_do_this)=>console.log(wanna_do_this)}


Just pass a parameter when you call that function in the component that receives it, what's the problem?

It's not clear to me what stops you from doing this.  When you attempt to pass this prop to a component, what do you try and what doesn't work as expected?

LoL. I thought i needed to send the data from inside the component to outside.
(Im codding all day im tired already sorry)

You just have to create a prop named as you want and pass it. For example:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
function CalledComponent ({onCustom}){
   // Here you'll be able to call this custom event/function.
   // Let's say I call it in useEffect.
   useEffect(onCustom, []);
   // Or maybe I call it in many events at the same time.
   return (<div onClick={onCustom} onHover={onCustom}>
         I'm called and I execute custom events when I'm clicked or hovered :D
   </div>);
}
// PropTypes stuff.
CalledComponent.propTypes = {
   onCustom: PropTypes.func,
};

So later I could simply call it and pass a function to it.
function ComponentThatCalls(){
    return (<CalledComponent onCustom={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}/>);
}


Thks its really simple lol,
Im tired so my head inst at 100%
